# ios system when to call respondsToSelector method

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

today, i saw code that UIView's category reload respondsToSelector and forwardInvocation. i donot understand why do this. this code intent to unite UITableview style in iOS6 and iOS7. i konw resolveInstanceMethod and forwardInvocation can work togather to change function in runtime. 
How to explain respondsToSelector and forwardInvocation. When ios call respondsToSelector?

i make a simple test,but it donot call respondsToSelector, the test code as follow:

```
@protocol MyViewDelegate <NSObject>//why cannot be <UIView>?
@optional
- (void)myViewDelegateMethod;
@end

@interface MyView : UIView
@property (nonatomic,weak) id<MyViewDelegate>delegate;
- (void)test;
@end

@implementation MyView

- (void)test{
    NSLog(@"%s",__func__);
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(myViewDelegateMethod)]) {
        [self.delegate myViewDelegateMethod];
    }
}

@end

@implementation UIView (FunctionChain)
- (BOOL)respondsToSelector:(SEL)aSelector{
     //when i call [myview test],can't execute this
     return [super respondsToSelector:aSelector];
}
@end
```

Comment: You aren't calling `[self respondsToSelector:]` though; you are calling `[self.delegate respondsToSelector:]`, so the category method will not be called, unless a `UIView` subclass was also the delegate to itself or another view (which is unlikely).

Comment: The `FunctionChain` category for `UIView` is bad. Never use a category to attempt to override a method. It's undefined behavior. Besides, that overridden method is pointless since it simply calls the `super` method.

Comment: thank you, the delegate is not a view@Droppy